# I am getting error like "expected identifier" when i try to use macros in my code

Tags: c++, c++11

I have written a macros but when i use the code i get expected identifier error.

Below is my macros

```
#define ITK(arguments)  \
{                       \
    int iFail=0;        \
    iFail = arguments;  \
    if(iFail != ITK_ok) \
{                      \
    char* s;            \
    TC_write_syslog("Following Method Retruns error "#arguments "\n");\
    TC_write_syslog("Error is in the line [%d] of the file ["__FILE__"]\n",[__LINE__]);\
    EMH_ask_error_text(iFail,&s);\
    TC_write_syslog("And the error is [%s]",s);\
    if(s!=0) MEM_FREE(s);\
}                           \
}
```

Comment: It’s hard to say without context, but your `[__LINE__]` is surely wrong.

Comment: Two things: Firstly, your question is off-topic, because it doesn't contain a [mcve], which might have guided you to the solution already. Secondly, C++ has variadic templates, so this type of code shouldn't be even remotely necessary. Remember, macros are evil!

Answer (score 0):

As Davis Herring said the reason is your `[__LINE__]`

When you are lost and you do not see where is the error on that kind of case look at the code after the pre processing, for instance using *g++* do `g++ -E < other flags except -c > -o temp.cc` and if you still don't see in *temp.cc* add line breaks in the interesting portion of code in *temp.cc* then compile *temp.cc* to look at compiler errors/warnings

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple typo to me. You need to remove `[` and `]` here:

```
TC_write_syslog("Error is in the line [%d] of the file ["__FILE__"]\n",[__LINE__]);
//                                                                     ^        ^
```

---

Note that instead of using printf's `%d` to insert `__LINE__` into a string at runtime, you can convert `__LINE__` to a string literal at compile-time:

```
#define STR(x) STR_(x)
#define STR_(x) #x
TC_write_syslog("Error is in the line " STR(__LINE__) " of the file ["__FILE__"]\n");
```